# Add internally saved video to gallery app android

Tags: android, android-file

I have a video saved in internal storage. i.e. /data/data//
Now I need to add this video to device gallery app. How should i do this? Tired below, but the video is not playing from gallery.

```
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "My video title");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/*");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
```

context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);`

Tried below too. But no luck.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAdded)));
```

Comment: Video isn't playing from device gallery app? How about check that video's codec first ?

Comment: Yes, video isn't playing from gallery app. If i copy that video from the internal folder to device DCIM folder it is playing fine. The actual video file is in internal folder of application. I just want to add that video to gallery.

Comment: So is there any error/exception message or media error code while played fail ?

Comment: No errors. I updated the question. please see.